# quicktime movie layering issues

Tags: html, css, quicktime, z-index, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have a site (link below) where the clients work displays on a long horizontal page. The menu is fixed on the left hand side and the images disappear under the menu when scrolling across.

The client has now uploaded quicktime movies which do not go under the menu like the images but scroll over the menu.

http://www.calebchurchill.com/projects/horny_dog/

I have tried to sort this using z-index but am so far been unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3500405.htm) - are you facing the same problem?

The OP there finally went on to use RealPlayer instead, hope it helps you...

Comment: sounds like the same problem - changing the embed code is awkward as the movies are embedded through wordpress plugins. I will investigate but unfortunately i think it has to be quicktime movies :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[Quicktime video appearing over Fixed DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045217/quicktime-video-appearing-over-fixed-div)

They use special quicktime params to make the Quicktime Player use the stackorder.
I haven´t tested it myself because its not exactly my solution, but it might help you, if you can access the embedding code of the player.

Comment: This is more like a comment. You would rather elaborate the answer. Please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)