# Quicktime video appearing over Fixed DIV

Tags: css, html, z-index, quicktime

I have an embedded quicktime video that is appearing over a fixed Div. I wrapped them both in DIVS with correct z-indexes, not working. How do I get the video under the div (position: fixed;)?

... Oh, and the problem is only occurring in Safari.

Comment: With "under the div", do you mean you want to cover the video with the div?

Comment: - yes. It is the navigation. When you resize the window to something, "too small", it covers the navigation on the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no clue how you're embedding it but `param name="wmode" value="transparent"` or `wmode="transparent"` will make it obey stacking order. param is for `object` and attribute is for `embed`